# How can you stream computer generated content on twitch

Tags: streaming, twitch

Due to my lack of knowledge about streaming on twitch, I have a hard time figuring out the what to search on google.

I'd like to write a program that generates graphs (for example two AIs playing a game against each other) and streams it on twitch. But I don't want the program to be running on my PC. I want the program to run on a remote machine, for example an EC2 instance on AWS.

I have seen discussions about streaming RTMP but I'm not sure if that's the best/right way of doing what I want to do.

I'd like to know how to do this or what to look for online.

I had initially posted this question on gaming but it was recommended to move it to superuser.

Comment: Have you looked at OBS? You could screen capture something showing the graphs. There are a couple other things I can think of, but I'm not quite sure if they would work.

Comment: This is way too broad. How to stream to Twitch would primarily be a question for Twitch themselves, and probably be answered by "use their client", but how to do it in some unsupported way using unknown APIs would first need you to define what resources and programs you have that *should* work but don't. This sounds a lot like you want us to recommend products, which would be off topic here.